# How to get offset from image in Positioned widget, which is bigger than device in Flutter

Tags: flutter, position, flutter-layout, gesture-recognition

Im trying to do this: https://medium.com/@alexander.arendar/dragging-zooming-and-placing-object-on-indoor-map-with-flutter-67667ef415ec
SVG file is loaded on Canvas. OnPanUpdate im changing the position of picture on device. Im trying to place some markers on this svg, but im unable to get the correct tap position.

Widget:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onLongPressEnd: _handlePutMarker,
      onPanUpdate: _handlePanUpdate,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.cyan[100],
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            height: double.infinity,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Stack(
              overflow: Overflow.visible,
              children: <Widget>[
                Positioned(
                  key: _keyRed,
                  top: top - (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4),
                  left: left - (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 6),
                  width: 100 * ratio,
                  child: FutureBuilder<DrawableRoot>(
                    future: svg.fromSvgString(rawSvg, rawSvg),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return CustomPaint(
                          painter: SvgPainter(snapshot.data, top, left, ratio,
                              markers, markerImage),
                        );
                      }
                      return Container();
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  left: 0,
                  top: 0,
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline),
                        onPressed: _handleZoomIn,
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle_outline),
                        onPressed: _handleZoomOut,
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.pause_circle_outline),
                        onPressed: () {
                          markers.removeLast();
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

OnPanUpdate:

```
void _handlePanUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    setState(() {
      top = top + details.delta.dy;
      left = left + details.delta.dx;
    });
  }
```

PutMarker:

```
void _handlePutMarker(LongPressEndDetails details) {
    setState(() {
      final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
      final Offset localOffset = box.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);

      markers.add(Offset(localOffset.dx, localOffset.dy));
    });
  }
```

Canvas:

```
@override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) async {
    try {
      size = Size(data.viewport.size.width, data.viewport.size.height);
      data.scaleCanvasToViewBox(canvas, Size(1000 * ratio, 1000 * ratio));
      data.draw(
        canvas,
        ColorFilter.srgbToLinearGamma(),
        Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 2148, 814),
      );

      Paint paint = Paint()..color = Colors.red;

      for (int i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        canvas.drawImage(markerImage, markers[i], paint);
      }
```